# Run jest debugger with react-scripts

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I want to use jest debugger. It comes pre-installed in react-scripts.
I want to render the component to chrome.

According to docs

```
node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand
```

After modifying it for react-scripts

```
node --inspect-brk node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand
```

I also tried:

```
node --inspect-brk node_modules/react-scripts/.bin/react-scripts.js --runInBand
```

I want to use it with react-scripts only because default one requires babel and other configurations.

According to docs

```
node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand
```

After modifying it for react-scripts

```
node --inspect-brk node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand
```

I also tried:

```
node --inspect-brk node_modules/react-scripts/.bin/react-scripts.js --runInBand
```